# Requiring a LuaJIT module in a subdir is overwriting a module of the same name in the parent dir

Tags: lua, require, luajit

I have a file setup like this:

```
main.lua  (requires 'mydir.b' and then 'b')
b.lua
mydir/
  b.so    (LuaJIT C module)
```

From main, I do this:

```
function print_loaded()
  for k, v in pairs(package.loaded) do print(k, v) end
end

print_loaded()
require 'mydir.b'
print_loaded()

-- This would now include 'mydir.b' instead of 'b':
local b = require 'b'
```

The outputs of the `print`s show that my call to `require 'mydir.b'` is setting the return value as the value of `package.loaded['b']` as well as the expected `package.loaded['mydir.b']`. I wanted to have `package.loaded['b']` left unset so that I can later `require 'b'` and not end up with the (in my opinion incorrectly) cached value from `mydir.b`.

My question is: What's a good way to deal with this?

In my case, I want to be able to copy around `mydir` as a subdir of any of my LuaJIT projects, and not have to worry about `mydir.whatever` polluting the module namespace by destroying any later `require`s of `whatever` at the parent directory level.

In anticipation of people saying, "just rename your modules!" Yes. I can do that. But I'd love to know if there's a better solution that allows me to simply not have to worry about the name collisions at all.

Comment: Does your `b.lua` use the `module` function by any chance?

Comment: No, it doesn't. This behavior appears to be independent of the contents of `b.lua`.

Comment: Does the `b.so` library set `packages.loaded` (ex. by using `module`) anywhere?

Comment: No, `b.so` doesn't use `module` anywhere. But! It does call `luaL_register`, which is probably causing the problem! Thanks for helping me realize that. I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was calling `luaL_register` incorrectly from within my `b.so`'s source file (`b.c`).

Here is the bad code that caused the problem:

```
static const struct luaL_reg b[] = {
  /* set up a list of function pointers here */
};

int luaopen_mydir_b(lua_State *L) {
  luaL_register(L, "b", b);  // <-- PROBLEM HERE (see below)
  return 1;                  // 1 = # Lua-visible return values on the stack.
}
```

The problem with the highlighted line is that it will specifically set `package.loaded['b']` to have the return value of this module when it's loaded. This can be fixed by replacing the line with this:

```
luaL_register(L, "mydir.b", b);
```

which will set `package.loaded['mydir.b']` instead, and thus leave room for later use of a module with the same name (without the `mydir` prefix).

I didn't realize this until long after I asked this question, when I finally got around to reading the official [docs for `luaL_register`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#luaL_register) for Lua 5.1, which is the version LuaJIT complies with.

Comment: IIRC, luaopen_whatever() is called with a single *modname* argument from require(), so it is probably more correct to use that instead of hardcoded name.

Comment: Or use `lua_newtable(L); luaL_register(L, NULL, b);`. Setting global variables from within modules is not best practice [any more](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2010-08/msg00443.html). A global named `mydir.b` wouldn't be that useful anyhow, because you'd have to write `_G["mydir.b"]` to actually use it.